# How to automate RSS file retrieval in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I'm working on a system that scrapes news articles from RSS files and passes them to a sentiment analysis API.

It is my first time working on a project of that scale. I'm at a stage where I can get raw text out of links that are in an RSS file. I now need to put in place a system that can automatically fetch RSS files when they are updated.

Any high-level ideas of how this could be achieved?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[feedparser](https://pythonhosted.org/feedparser/index.html) does a good job of sourcing RSS feeds.  It also has features not used in this example for efficiently getting new items *ETags*

Google gave me the site https://blog.feedspot.com/world_news_rss_feeds/ for a source of multiple RSS news feeds. I just scraped this to get a dictionary.  Then it's a simple case of looping over RSS sources.

```
import feedparser
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.parse, xml.sax
import pandas as pd

# get some RSS feeds....
resp = requests.get("https://blog.feedspot.com/world_news_rss_feeds/")
soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.content.decode(), "html.parser")
rawfeeds = soup.find_all("h2")
feeds = {}
for rf in rawfeeds:
    a = rf.find("a")
    if a is not None:
        feeds[a.string.replace("RSS Feed", "").strip()] = urllib.parse.parse_qs(a['href'])["q"][0].replace("site:","")
        
# now source them all into a dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame()
for k, url in feeds.items():
    try:
        df = pd.concat([df, pd.json_normalize(feedparser.parse(url)["entries"]).assign(Source=k)])
    except (Exception, xml.sax.SAXParseException):
        print(f"invalid xml: {url}")
```

#### re-entrant

1. use *etag* and *modified* capabilities of `feedparser`
2. persist dataframes so when run again it takes off from where it left off

I would use threading so that it is not purely sequential.  Obviously with threading you need to think about synchronising your save points.  Then you can just run in a scheduler to periodically source new items in RSS feeds and get associated article.

```
import feedparser, requests, newspaper
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.parse, xml.sax
from pathlib import Path
import pandas as pd

if not Path().cwd().joinpath("news").is_dir(): Path.cwd().joinpath("news").mkdir()
p = Path().cwd().joinpath("news")
    
# get some RSS feeds....
if p.joinpath("rss.pickle").is_file():
    dfrss = pd.read_pickle(p.joinpath("rss.pickle"))
else:
    resp = requests.get("https://blog.feedspot.com/world_news_rss_feeds/")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.content.decode(), "html.parser")
    rawfeeds = soup.find_all("h2")
    feeds = []
    for rf in rawfeeds:
        a = rf.find("a")
        if a is not None:
            feeds.append({"name":a.string.replace("RSS Feed", "").strip(),
                         "url":urllib.parse.parse_qs(a['href'])["q"][0].replace("site:",""),
                         "etag":"","status":0, "dubug_msg":"", "modified":""})
    dfrss = pd.DataFrame(feeds).set_index("url")
if p.joinpath("rssdata.pickle").is_file():
    df = pd.read_pickle(p.joinpath("rssdata.pickle"))
else:
    df = pd.DataFrame({"id":[],"link":[]})

# now source them all into a dataframe. head() is there for testing purposes
for r in dfrss.head(5).itertuples():
#     print(r.Index)
    try:
        fp = feedparser.parse(r.Index, etag=r.etag, modified=r.modified)
        if fp.bozo==1: raise Exception(fp.bozo_exception)
    except Exception as e:
        fp = feedparser.FeedParserDict(**{"etag":r.etag, "entries":[], "status":500, "debug_message":str(e)})
    # keep meta information of what has already been sourced from a RSS feed
    if "etag" in fp.keys(): dfrss.loc[r.Index,"etag"] = fp.etag
    dfrss.loc[r.Index,"status"] = fp.status
    if "debug_message" in fp.keys(): dfrss.loc[r.Index,"debug_mgs"] = fp.debug_message
    # 304 means upto date... getting 301 and entries hence test len...
    if len(fp["entries"])>0:
        dft = pd.json_normalize(fp["entries"]).assign(Source=r.Index)
        # don't capture items that have already been captured...
        df = pd.concat([df, dft[~dft["link"].isin(df["link"])]])

# save to make re-entrant...
dfrss.to_pickle(p.joinpath("rss.pickle"))
df.to_pickle(p.joinpath("rssdata.pickle"))

# finally get the text...
if p.joinpath("text.pickle").is_file():
    dftext = pd.read_pickle(p.joinpath("text.pickle"))
else:
    dftext = pd.DataFrame({"link":[], "text":[]})

# head() is there for testing purposes
for r in df[~df["link"].isin(dftext["link"])].head(5).itertuples():
    a = newspaper.Article(r.link)
    a.download()
    a.parse()
    dftext = dftext.append({"link":r.link, "text":a.text},ignore_index=True)
    
dftext.to_pickle(p.joinpath("text.pickle"))
```

An analysis of data that has been retrieved.
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply Rob. I have the architecture setup to do just that, from top to bottom. Use Feedparser to extract data from RSS feed, I then use newspaper3k to go through each of the links in the RSS feed and extract only the article, which is then stored in a DF, and passed to an API for sentiment analysis. The question is more relating to automating that process of reading the RSS file, since obviously when news are posted and the RSS file is updated, at the moment, the system does not re-execute this process. I'm trying to replicate a live-feed type feature. Hope this is clearler now

Comment: I've updated - it really is about making sourcing process re-entrant and capturing what's new.  The features are there in `feedparser` and then being smart about sourcing what you don't already have.  Using a database maybe smarter,  but for simplicity I've use pickle files.